# Can't open codeblocks

Tags: codeblocks

I am using windows 8.1. after upgrading from 8 to 8.1 codeblocks works well but after a week I found this.

Code blocks starts but don't open. just show a thumbnail in the bar.
[image]

I have done all of the restart , turn off pc , uninstall , reinstall the latest version .... 
but nothing helps. 
Here is an additional image that might help ..

[image]

Comment: That happened to me too, but it got OK after an uninstall and reinstall

Comment: I have tried it so many times ... but no result ..

Answer (score 4):

In windows,

- Activate "show hidden folder"
- Go to C:\Users<user_name>\AppData\Roaming\CodeBlocks
- rename the `default.conf` file to "default.conf.old" or anything u like.

**By this, u will remove all the settings of codeblocks and in the next launch, you will get new options to choose from.**

Note: Reinstall won't help in this problem.

Answer (score 0):

@user3712917's answer didn't work for me. What I did was delete the entire C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\CodeBlocks folder. This solved the issue.